# What is the equivalent of Ruby's __method__ for Elixir?

Tags: elixir

How can one do something like the following:

```
rec = fn ->
  receive do
  after
     1000 -> __function__
  end
end

rec.()
```

Where **function** points to the current function, similar to how **method** in Ruby returns a symbol to the current method.

Answer (score 0):

*Sidenote*: there should not be any reason to query current function name. In Ruby we have `__callee__`, that was handy for distinguishing aliases, <sub>unless got broken in 2.3,</sub> but `__method__` itself does not make much sense.

Anyway, one might use [`:erlang.process_info/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_info-2):

```
{:current_function, {module, function, arity}} = \
      :erlang.process_info(:erlang.self(), :current_function)
```

Example:

```
defmodule A, do: def a, do: :erlang.process_info(:erlang.self(), :current_function)
A.a
#⇒ {:current_function, {A, :a, 0}}
```